# How to link UISwitch to UITableViewController in IOS7 via storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiswitch

The Setup:
I have a tableviewcontroller class and I have a custom View Cell class that defines whats in it. I used storyboard to configure it and link everything.

I have some persistent state for the switch in my core data model and the Entity and its associated Class, lets call it "Chain". The reason I mention that is to confirm that I have persistent state for my Switch state and its built into my Core data and the data is getting grabbed just fine.

The Problem:

I have to set the state of the switch in my CoreData (specifically in my fetchedresults controller) and to save it, I need access to the particular object that i use to give TableViewCell its values and I don't know how to grab it. The solutions I have seen so far seem to be linked to programmatically creating the switch within the viewcontroller class, where as I have a storyboard created switch linked to a TablViewCell thats been assigned to it.

I originally thought that just making it available through my TableViewCell class and referencing to it would do the trick: ie:
    - (IBAction)set_switchStatus:(id)sender {

```
UITabBarController *tab = (UITabBarController *) self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *) [[tab viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];
ChainMainTableView *ctvc = (ChainMainTableView *)[[nav viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];

Chain *chain = ctvc.chain;

NSLog(@"%@", chain);



//Call my API


}
```

Going Over to my TableView Controller Class, my cellForRowAtIndexPath looks like this:
(Note: chain is a property I added to the class of type Chain so I could refer to it easily from other classes.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ChainCell";
//PLACE WHERE I CHANGED UITABLEVIEWCELL
CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

// Save the chain for use in other classes and also Configure the cell...
self.chain = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.chainValue.text = self.chain.activity;
 cell.repsDueValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ reps", self.chain.reps_due];
cell.activity_status.on = self.chain.activity_status.boolValue;


if (cell.activity_status.isOn)
{
    cell.activity_status.enabled = NO;
}
else
{
    cell.activity_status.enabled = YES;
}

return cell;
```

}

So All I really need is my UISwitch to refer to the specific Object thats providing data to the cell in that row. Then, I need to use an identifier value in that to set my CoreData values accordingly. I haven't got it to work yet, ANY tips would be much appreciated.

Edit:

So I liked the Subclassing idea, but it would have gone a bit against the spirit of the separation I was trying to get with all the classes. I think I have a solution given some more reading up on stack and fin-nicking and it looks like this:

```
UITabBarController *tab = (UITabBarController *) self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *) [[tab viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];
ChainMainTableView *ctvc = (ChainMainTableView *)[[nav viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];
CGPoint hitPoint = [self convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:ctvc.tableView];
NSIndexPath *hitIndex = [ctvc.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:hitPoint];

self.currentChain = [ctvc.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:hitIndex];
```

And now I have everything I need to get things to work the way i want. I m not sure if its very efficient, but it gets the job done without ( i m pretty sure) breaking anything.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest sub-classing UITableViewCell so that it contains the UISwitch and a `chain` property that can be filled when the cell is created in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  When the UISwitch's value is changed, the custom cell can fire off either a NSNotification to an interested observer, or save it to the managedContext itself, &c.

Comment: I liked your approach, but I think I have a solution that avoids the subclassing. This feels more in line with the way I've learned the code up to this point, I've included my solution in my main message. Ps: it won't let me upvote your response. Any clues?

Comment: I assume you can't upvote me because your Stack rep is too "new", you can only accept or ignore answers; don't sweat it and happy coding.